# Need to type -4x - 6

Tags: math-mode

I am new to LaTeX.

I need to type:

> -4x - 6

I used following command:

`$ –4x – 6$`

It gave me the output as `4x6`:

How can I type `-4x - 6` instead of `4x6`?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site :) `$-4x - 6$` is the correct syntax, which means that we need a lot lot more information, because there's something else going on here. Could you please provide a complete [Minimum Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: You're using an en dash, when you should be using a hyphen. The two are different characters, and LaTeX doesn't know what to do with an en dash. Difference: `–` vs `-`.

Comment: Good eye you two (Christian Hupfer and Arun Debray)! I was just going down the generic response road :P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh I didn't mean I had an answer ready, I just saw correct-looking syntax and thought 'better comment asking for an MWE' - whereas the more attentive of us spotted the actual problem :P

Comment: @Au101: Yes, but Arun's comment is better than mine.

Comment: Thanks guys...
You saved my time. its all about hypen and dash issue !!! :(

Comment: @ArunDebray Would you maybe write that as an answer?

Comment: @hooy: just did it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a subtle issue – you're using an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) `U+2013` when you should be using a hyphen `U+002D`. The en dash isn't ASCII, so the TeX interpreter doesn't know what to do with it.

The difference: `–` vs `-`.

(Converted to an answer at [hooy's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278714/need-to-type-4x-6?noredirect=1#comment734781_278714).)